# Is there a way to read a QR code in TestCafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there a way to read a QR code in TestCafe? I have an image of a QR code and I want to read it, then assert it is going to the correct URL.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a mobile phone connected to the same network to scan the QR code, is this any good? more information here: https://testautomationu.applitools.com/testcafe-tutorial/chapter14.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @JeanCamargo! That's not quite what I'm looking for, though. I want to automate the testing of a QR code. My use case is that I have a QR code, (either an image or on a website), I'd like to read it with TestCafe, and then confirm I'm directed to the correct URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any third-party library to parse a QR code and check the result in the TestCafe test. The example below shows how to do it with the [qrcode-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-reader) module:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import axios from 'axios';
import QrCode from 'qrcode-reader';
import Jimp from 'jimp';

fixture`QR Code`
    .page`https://goqr.me/`;

function decodeQrCode (buffer) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Jimp.read(buffer, (err, image) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
    
            const qr = new QrCode();
    
            qr.callback = (err, value) => {
                if (err)
                    reject(err);

                resolve(value.result);
            }
    
            qr.decode(image.bitmap);
        });
    });
}

test('Test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#qrcode-field-text-text', 'example.com', { replace: true })
        .wait(1000);

    const imageUrl = await Selector('#qrcode-preview-image').getAttribute('src');
    const response = await axios.get(imageUrl,  { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
    const buffer   = Buffer.from(response.data, "utf-8");
    const url      = await decodeQrCode(buffer);

    await t.expect(url).eql('example.com');
});
```